# angular ui-router state template not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angular-ui-router

I created a basic angular app with ui-router. I am serving partial template from index.html with a script tag but I get this error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:1337/home.html
```

Here is my code.

```
var app = angular.module('smApp', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '',
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl'
            })
    }])
    .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.home = 1;
    }]);
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/script" id="home.html">
    <div>Home Page {{home}}</div>
</script>
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change type attribute of your script tag that contains template code. For Angular, in order to recognize the template, you need to change type attribute to 'text/ng-template' from 'text/script'

Your index.html should be

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <div>Home Page {{home}}</div>
</script>
<div ui-view></div>
```